# Calling Python script from console in a special Conda enviroment (to use libraries like TensorFlow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, cmd, anaconda, spyder

I am currently using Python in a special software, which only has a Matlab API. Therefore,
I call Python in Matlab from the console and get values back from Python, which works well. Here an
example of the Matlab code.

```
cd '\\path';
commandStr = ['C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe program.py'];
[status, commandOut] = system(commandStr);
disp(commandOut);
```

Unfortunetely, I want to use some TensorFlow libraries, which are only working if I start
Spyder in my own created conda environment, because there are not in the Python standard library (this is how it works in my company). These libraries aren't working if I call a script in Matlab like in the example above. Do anyone know if I can open program.py in a special conda environment. As I am only doing a Windows CMD call in Matlab, the code in CMD would be completely equal.

Please do not mention, that I also can use the Python/Matlab interface for this, because I am calling also different APIs in Python to finite elements simulation programs, which are not working in this interface.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can run two commands in one:

`conda activate your_environment_name & C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe program.py`

This will activate the conda environment containing Tensorflow, etc. and run your program within the environment. Make sure that your environment is in the conda PATH variable.

Let me know if you have any questions or problems!